# An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias. Consider writing '[key: string]:

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular application i have this code

```
  getLocalStreams: () => {
        [key: Stream['key']]: Stream;
    };
```

> 

getting this error on compilation

```
    An index signature parameter type cannot be a type alias. Consider writing '[key: string]: { readonly id: string; readonly key: string;
> readonly participantId: string; readonly origin: "local" | "remote";
> readonly isAudioEnabled: boolean; readonly isVideoEnabled: boolean;
> ... 4 more ...; readonly isConfigured: boolean; }' instead
```

any solution to fix this issue, Thanks

Comment: Please update the question with more information. For a start: What's the definition of `Stream` that you're using? What does `Stream["key"]` resolve to? Because despite the wording of the error, you **can** use `[key: Stream["key"]]: Stream` as an index signature (https://tsplay.dev/Wzqorm), provided `Stream["key"]` resolves to a [valid index signature type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures). Please add a [mre] to the question, something we can copy and paste to see the problem locally. Ideally, also include that same code in...

Comment: ...[the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) but beware of [this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386543/why-does-my-typescript-playground-link-break-when-i-use-insert-hyperlink) posting the link (workaround included).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean to write this? We indicate the key will be of type string and the value of type `Stream`

```
getLocalStreams: () => {
    [key: string]: Stream;
};
```

Comment: Your playground doesn't replicate the error on `dummy2`, and otherwise just tells the OP to do what the error message is already telling the OP to do.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks i updated